# Change PK value in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

May be this question is duplicate.I check up this answer for my problem.But nothing of them solve my problem. Finally my question like it.
I have a person table like it.
[image]
I want to change ID=99980 and  ID=99982 with each other.
ID is PK and auto increment.

Comment: Your question is marked as `tsql` and `oracle`, but Oracle uses PL/SQL, not T-SQL.

Comment: You cannot have two records with same ID in your identity column and a primary key. You can update the value in PK field but it should not be duplicate. Since the data you are trying is duplicate you cannot achieve this.

Comment: thanks Justin Skiles. I update .

Comment: If ID is a PK, then how would you duplicate the value 99982?

Answer (score 6):

You mean you want to **ex**-change them?

If so, you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET ID =
    CASE ID
    WHEN 99980 THEN 99982
    ELSE 99980
    END
WHERE ID IN (99980, 99982);
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abeac/1)

- This works out-of-box if the DBMS enforces constraints when the SQL command **finishes** (Oracle and MS SQL Server).
- If the DBMS enforces constraints **during** command execution, but also supports deferred constraints, it can be made to work by by deferring the key on ID (PostgreSQL).
- On a DBMS that supports neither (MySQL), you'll have to split it to 3 UPDATES using a known unoccupied ID as an intermediary, for example: 99980 -> -1, 99982 -> 99980, -1 -> 99982.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach with the same effect would be to update the non-key columns that differ between the two records:

```
UPDATE PERSON SET FIRST_NAME='Mary', Age=25 WHERE ID=99980
UPDATE PERSON SET FIRST_NAME='John', Age=45 WHERE ID=99982
```

Comment: If I know only ID value,what should I do?

Comment: In that case, I like @Branko's first suggestion - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21161807/2084

Comment: There are couple of caveats with this solution: (1) It won't work if there is an alternate key (probably not the case here). (2) If ID is referenced from another table via a FOREIGN KEY with ON UPDATE CASCADE (not supported under Oracle), that referential action won't be triggered (which may or may not be desired). (3) In general case, you'll have to have an additional step to actually memorize the values from one of these rows, otherwise you won't known what they are after the row gets overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.Reset  Auto Increment property & Primary Key (Put them OFF)

Step 2.Run these update commands:

```
Update YourTableName SET  ID=99982 WHERE ID=99980
```

and

```
Update YourTableName SET  ID=99980 WHERE FIRST_NAME='Mary' AND ID=99982
```

Step 3.Set Auto Increment Property & Primary Key again (Turn them ON).

Done

Comment: Turning off a key (or any other) constraint would allow it to be violated by a concurrent transaction, so it is generally not advisable during "normal" database operation. Temporarily disabling constraints is usually done to increase performance when importing huge amounts of data, when you know the data is "clean" and there are no concurrent clients.